# variable array names in Excel for MAC 2011

Tags: arrays, macos, excel

I have a piece of code that uses a hundred or so array names, (my example below only uses three), each one of which contain a different number of elements. I'm trying to reference the array name using a variable, "i", where "i" is used to index the array name and the sheet name.

The line of code starting with "Selection.Replace" is failing with an "application defined or object defined error"
This works fine in Excel 2007 for windows but fails in Excel for MAC 2011.

What changes should I make to get this back working again, (besides just using Excel 2007 or 2010)?

Cheers!

```
hist1 array("a","b","c","d","x")
hist2 array("a","e","f","g")
hist3 array("a","b","c","d","g","x")

i = 1
Do While i < 4
    j = 0
    Select Case i
        Case 1
            cnt = 4
        Case 2
            cnt = 3
        Case 3
            cnt = 5
    End Select
    Do While j < cnt
        Sheets(i).Select
        Selection.Replace What:="hist" & i & "(" & cnt & ")", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        j = j + 1
    Loop
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.
is seems that SearchFormat and ReplaceFormat are not valid parameters in this version of Excel